# Apache Nifi: load data from REST to Druid

Tags: etl, apache-nifi, druid, bigdata

I'm using Apache NiFi.

What is the proper way to load data from REST API to [Druid](http://druid.io)?

Answer (score 1):

There are not any apache community based connectors for Druid yet but we really should make one soon.  Hopefully someone will contribute one soon.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

1. Option 1 A simple way to solve this it to first make NiFi dump the
   data into a Kafka Queue Then point Druid Realtime nodes to pull data
   out of the Kafka Queue to index data on realtime.
2. Option 2 is to bring the data from NiFi to Storm cluster apply some
   transformation (eg Stream joins ..) if needed then use Tranquility
   to push data to Druid.

I am not an NiFi expert, but i think you will always need something like kafka to buffer events since i don't think NiFi does offer a buffering queue (again am not 100% sure about this claim).

Comment: NiFi connections support a concept called ["back pressure"](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#back-pressure), which can limit execution by a data size/count threshold and propagate that information back along a flow, effectively buffering data until it is released.